# XmlSchema.Read gives COMException "Catastrophic failure"

Tags: .net, debugging, com

I've got a utility class with a few method relating to XML schemas. Without any code changes nor any know changes to the environment, it has suddenly started to fail systematically.

The method that fails:

```
public static XmlSchema GetSchema(string xsdFileName)
{
    string path = MyConfiguration.XmlSchemaLocation;
    if (!path.EndsWith(@"\"))
    {
        path += @"\";
    }

    path += xsdFileName;
    return XmlSchema.Read(File.OpenRead(path), null);
}
```

The stack trace shows XmlSchema.Read is internally attempting to construct a Parser object, and the constructor of this attempts to read some configuration, and this in turn leads to some policy evidence being examined, and then it blows up with a COMException with an error code which, if I understand this correctly, provides no more information than the error being unexpected!

Here's the exception:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8000FFFF): Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))
   at System.Security.Policy.PEFileEvidenceFactory.GetLocationEvidence(SafePEFileHandle peFile, SecurityZone& zone, StringHandleOnStack retUrl)
   at System.Security.Policy.PEFileEvidenceFactory.GenerateLocationEvidence()
   at System.Security.Policy.PEFileEvidenceFactory.GenerateEvidence(Type evidenceType)
   at System.Security.Policy.AssemblyEvidenceFactory.GenerateEvidence(Type evidenceType)
   at System.Security.Policy.Evidence.GetHostEvidenceNoLock(Type type)
   at System.Security.Policy.Evidence.GetHostEvidence(Type type, Boolean markDelayEvaluatedEvidenceUsed)
   at System.Security.Policy.AppDomainEvidenceFactory.GenerateEvidence(Type evidenceType)
   at System.Security.Policy.Evidence.GetHostEvidenceNoLock(Type type)
   at System.Security.Policy.Evidence.RawEvidenceEnumerator.MoveNext()
   at System.Security.Policy.Evidence.EvidenceEnumerator.MoveNext()
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths.GetEvidenceInfo(AppDomain appDomain, String exePath, String& typeName)
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths.GetTypeAndHashSuffix(AppDomain appDomain, String exePath)
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths..ctor(String exePath, Boolean includeUserConfig)
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths.GetPaths(String exePath, Boolean includeUserConfig)
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationHost.RequireCompleteInit(IInternalConfigRecord record)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSection(String configKey)
   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName)
   at System.Xml.Schema.Parser..ctor(SchemaType schemaType, XmlNameTable nameTable, SchemaNames schemaNames, ValidationEventHandler eventHandler)
   at System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema.Read(XmlReader reader, ValidationEventHandler validationEventHandler)
   at MyProj.Common.XSDValidator.GetSchema(String xsdFileName)
   at ...
```

Any idea how to investigate this further? Does anyone know what kind of thing may have caused this to start happening (e.g. a corrupt user profile for the identity under which the process is executing)?

This has happened in a production envioronment and I really have no idea how to proceed to figure out what has caused it, or to fix it.

In case it's relevant: The code is hosted in a console application. Note that the code has successfully accessed configuration shortly before it blows up. (The "MyConfiguration" class is another utility class that is basically a thin layer encapsulating a bunch of appSettings keys that uses the ordinary System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager class.)

Windows version:

```
OS Name:                   Microsoft® Windows Server® 2008 Datacenter
OS Version:                6.0.6002 Service Pack 2 Build 6002
OS Manufacturer:           Microsoft Corporation
OS Configuration:          Member Server
OS Build Type:             Multiprocessor Free
```

Comment: FYI: Path.Combine() might clean up your code a little bit

Comment: It is an environmental problem, a low-level CLR call to determine where the assembly is stored is failing.  Tends to be caused by over-eager anti-malware or a networking problem.  SysInternals' tools are a decent way to find the underlying problem, like Process Monitor.  Your program's .config file is the trigger, we can't see it.

Comment: @HansPassant It can't be the contents of the config file. The program is a batch that reads files from an input directory, and run via Windows Task Scheduler. There are many different input folders processed with different schedules, and only one of them fails - systematically - in this manner.

Comment: similar not-dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12791207/catastrophic-failure-when-impersonate-other-user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program was being executed via Task Scheduler. The instances that failed were running under minimum priveliges.

I reckon a SecurityException with a sensible description would have made more sense, but once the scheduled task was configured to run as a more priveliged process, the problem disappeared.

Comment: I changed it to Run with Highest Privileages. Then also, it is not working. Same error as you had but with the code "xslTransform.Load(value);" I don't know what to do from here