# Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED SharePoint 2013

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

This exception appears,
"Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED"
When I am trying to upload files to SharePoint 2013
It only appears on the production server but it works well on the development server.
Any suggestions?!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Impersonation and also reading config file then have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12791207/catastrophic-failure-when-impersonate-other-user).